# Creating and replacing new files with same title

Tags: java, swing

I have an existing text file. However, I want to overwrite the file, this includes deleting some words in the file. Therefore I think it would be easier if I write the data into a file with the same name and hope that the previous file will be overwrite, but this is not true. How can I do that?

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
int status = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

if(status ==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();

    PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(f.getName()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You've more or less done it, except that you didn't store a reference to the `PrintWriter` so you could actually write something to it, and you needlessly threw away the path information from the `File`.

The correct form would be

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
// pw.println()/print()/write() etc.
pw.close();
```